# PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod for Google Calendar API only returning 1 event

Tags: powershell, google-calendar-api

I am calling the Google Calendar API and requesting a list of all events in my calendar. However, I am only getting a single event returned. There are over 40 events in the calendar.

```
$CalURL="https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events"

$header=@{
    Authorization = "Bearer $($tokens.access_token)"
    maxResults='2500'        
}


Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $header -Uri $CalURL -Method Get -ContentType 'application/json'
```

Comment: What happens if you _don't_ specify `maxResults`? (default should be 250)

Comment: Same result, only a single event is returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When getting events with the Google Calendar API, it's important to know that all results are paginated and it is not required for Google to return all events in one page, even if all your events would fit on one.

This is the definition of the `maxResults` parameter as per the [Calendar API reference](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list):

> Maximum number of events returned on one result page. **The number of events in the resulting page may be less than this value, *or none at all*, even if there are more events matching the query**. Incomplete pages can be detected by a non-empty `nextPageToken` field in the response. By default the value is 250 events. The page size can never be larger than 2500 events. Optional.

To fix this, you must implement a loop to get all the events and use `nextPageToken`:

```
$CalURL="https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events"

$header=@{
    Authorization = "Bearer $($tokens.access_token)"
    maxResults='2500'        
}


$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $header -Uri $CalURL -Method Get -ContentType 'application/json'

$FullResults = @()
$result.items | ForEach-Object { $FullResults += $_ }

# Check if the results have a value for nextPageToken
while($null -ne $result.nextPageToken) {
    $header=@{
        Authorization = "Bearer $($tokens.access_token)"
        maxResults='2500'
        nextPageToken="$($result.nextPageToken)"        
    }

    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $header -Uri $CalURL -Method Get -ContentType 'application/json'

    $result.items | ForEach-Object { $FullResults += $_ }
}

$FullResults
```

The above should loop until all pages have been received

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. My original code was written some time ago and it was working, its not until I went to use it again that it was no longer doing what I expected it to. Thank you.